# Network sharing with Raspberry extremely slow

Tags: networking, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, samba

I have set up a samba server with raspberry, but the problem is that is extremely slow. I mainly use it to watch my photos, so each file is around 5MB maximum in size. The raspberry is connected to a gigabit switch, and I watch the photos through a pc connected through Ethernet.

This is iperf

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ iperf -s -p 10000
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 10000
TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  4] local 192.168.1.200 port 10000 connected with 192.168.1.112 port 52907
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec   111 MBytes  92.7 Mbits/sec
[  5] local 192.168.1.200 port 10000 connected with 192.168.1.112 port 53695
[  5]  0.0-10.0 sec   108 MBytes  89.9 Mbits/sec
[  4] local 192.168.1.200 port 10000 connected with 192.168.1.112 port 55175
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec   109 MBytes  91.1 Mbits/sec
[  5] local 192.168.1.200 port 10000 connected with 192.168.1.112 port 55760
[  5]  0.0-10.0 sec   110 MBytes  92.2 Mbits/sec
[  4] local 192.168.1.200 port 10000 connected with 192.168.1.112 port 55972
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec   110 MBytes  92.1 Mbits/sec
```

which is totally fine given the 100 Mbit/s card of the pi.

I read the photo from a USB hard disk, through which I reach roughly 45 MB/s. Hence, I would expect to download a single photo in roughly half of a second, which is not true. Currently, the time varies between 3 and 5 seconds, which is way too much.

Any advice about this?

Answer (score 0):

The read off the disk/ssd may be slow to start up and only settle into 45MB/s after a few seconds.  So most of the time could be spent in the initial strategy figuring out how to read the image file from the storage.  Once that's done, it quickly reads it and sends it.

Comment: Do you know how can I test if this is the problem? If it is, any idea about the solution?

Comment: I tried writing/reading a file to the disk. Same speed as before, so this should not be the issue.

Comment: @lbedogni, try reading a few thousand small files and sending them over the network in as few bulk writes as you can. time that vs reading 1 large file of roughly the same size as the sum total of the sizes of the small ones. you can generate files for both experiments by writing random stuff to them. make sure they are not cached after writing. probably just power down the device after you write the files.